# Python pass tab "\t" as argument

Tags: python

I have the following Python script named `test.py`. The goal is to let Python recognize tab. How should I do that?

```
import sys
input = sys.argv[1]
if __name__ == "__main__":
    print input == "\t"
```

When I pass `python test.py "\t"` to the command line, why do I get a `False`?

---

**[Update]**

I changed the code according to first two comments below:

```
import sys
someArgs = sys.argv[1]
if __name__ == "__main__":
    print someArgs
    print someArgs == '\t'
```

When I pass `python test.py '\t'`, I get

```
\t
False
```

---

**[Update 2]**

Unfortunately, I am using Windows command prompt, not *nix systems.

---

**[Quick & dirty solution]**

When `"\t"` is passed as argument in command line, I can try to detect it as `"\\t"` and manually assign it to tab in Python. For example,

```
import sys
someArgs = sys.argv[1]
if __name__ == "__main__":
    if someArgs == "\\t":
        pythonTab = "\t"
        print pythonTab
```

From command line, `python test.py "\t"` will produce a tab as output. Anyone has more elegant solutions?

Comment: What happens when you `print input`? Also avoid using that variable name because you are shadowing the function name `input`

Comment: Probably relevant (if OP is using bash): http://superuser.com/questions/362235/how-do-i-enter-a-literal-tab-character-in-a-bash-shell

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Backslash has a special meaning both in Python and in the command-line.

Do you want to detect a single tab character? Then you are comparing it correctly: `input == "\t"` is correct. But it's system-dependent to pass a tab character in the command-line. I don't know how to do it on Windows. On Unix with Bash, the command-line should look like:

```
python test.py $'\t'
```

or

```
python test.py $'\011'
```

See more info about the `$'` syntax in Bash here: http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#ANSI_002dC-Quoting

---

Do you want to detect two characters: a backslash and a t? Then you should compare it as: `input == "\\t"` or `input == r"\t"`. I don't know how to pass a backslash in the command-line on Windows. On Unix with Bash, the command-line should look like:

```
python test.py '\t'
```

See more info about the `'` syntax in Bash here: http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Single-Quotes

I recommend adding the following debug info generation to your program:

```
print repr(argv[1])
print argv[1].encode('hex')
```

Comment: I used to write Python on Mac. My current company uses Windows so I am clueless. Thanks for your information!

Answer (score 1):

You have two issues here.

First is that is that the `\t` is only functional in a Python script - you need the literal tab character in the command line.

Second is [how to enter a literal tab on the command line](https://superuser.com/a/362244)

You enter `command $'\t'`

So try this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys
in_part = sys.argv[1]
if __name__ == "__main__":
    print 'cmd[1]={}'.format(in_part)
    print in_part == "\t"
```

And for the command line:

```
tab.py $'\t'
```

Answer (score -1):

If you make sure your argument is always quoted, "\t", you could use:

```
ast.literal_eval(in_part)
```