# How to split a line based on argument specified by user through argparse module?

Tags: python

I want my program to take an argument through the argparse module which will be a delimiter on which lines in the input table are to be split on. However, this does not work, and the lines remain unsplit. Any ideas on how my goal can be achieved?

That is how I call my program:
`python $scripts/split_tab.py --tab my_tab --dm "\t"`

The code inside looks like this:

```
import os, sys
import argparse

ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()

ap.add_argument('--tab',required=True,type=str,help='Input table')
ap.add_argument('--dm',required=True,type=str,help='Delimiter string used in the table')

args = ap.parse_args()

tab = args.tab
my_delim = str(args.dm)

with open (tab) as fh:
    for line in fh:
        lines = line.strip().split(my_delim)
        print(lines)
```

Comment: I just tried your code, and it works for me. I think you just need to remove the doublescores when you call it from the command line. Try calling your code as: `python $scripts/split_tab.py --tab my_tab --dm \t` and see what happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23817939/python-pass-tab-t-as-argument) is an answer how to pass special characrters into python scripts.

I've print `args` value and get following output:

```
args = ap.parse_args()
print(args)
Out: 
Namespace(dm='\\t', tab='my_tab')
```

so, `args.dm` is not a `\t`, but `'\\t'` string. You can pass `\t` as explained in an answer mentioned above:

`python $scripts/split_tab.py --tab my_tab --dm $'\t'`

so, argparser stores `\t` value, you can check it via

```
print(args.dm == '\t')
Out:
True
```

Or you can compare `args.dm` with `'\\t'` string and replace it with `\t` symbol.

Comment: Thanks, it works along with solution provided by Luke Brady.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following changes:

At the top:

```
import re
```

Update your lines line to be:

```
lines = re.split(my_delim,line.strip())
```

Comment: Thank you for this partial solution!